# In English, there is a difference between "envy" and "jealousy." Does this same distinction exist in Spanish?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sustantivos

Primero, mi pregunta en español:
En inglés, hay una diferencia entre "envy" y "jealousy."  ¿Existe esta misma distincción en español?

Details in English:
If so, I am assuming that "**envidia**" corresonds with "**envy**" and "**celos**" with "**jealousy**."  Correct?

As requested, I am going to add some definitions.  Though I had many online resources to choose from, I really liked the way it was explained at Vocabulary.com, perhaps because it most closely resembled what I had remembered being taught in school.  First, the definitions:

> ### [**envy**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/envy)
>
> > **a feeling of grudging admiration and desire to have something that is possessed by another**
> >
> > **spite and resentment at seeing the success of another (personified as one of the deadly sins)**
>
> ### [**jealousy**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/jealousy)
>
> > **a feeling of jealous envy (especially of a rival)**
> >
> > **zealous vigilance**

*Though "envy" can be both a noun and a verb, to keep things simple, I only added the definitions of it as a noun.*

Vocabulary.com actually devotes an entire page to the nuances in meaning between envy and jealousy.  In essence, the difference is this:

> ### **Envy is when you want what someone else has, but jealousy is when you're worried someone's trying to take what you have.**

For more details and examples visit [**Vocabulary.com's page on envy and jealousy.**](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/envy-jealousy/)

I would rewrite this last addition in Spanish, but virtually the same thing is said in rodrigo's answer below.

Detalles en español:
Si lo es, estoy asumiendo que "envy" corresponde con "envidia" y "jealousy" con "celos."  ¿Correcto?

Comment: Una pregunta interesante. ¿Podrías incluir las definiciones en inglés de _envy_ y _jealousy_ para que podamos ver con claridad la diferencia en los términos originales?

Comment: Gracias, @Charlie, por tu sugerencia.  Fue una idea excelente y mis disculpas por no haberlo visto antes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the definitions from the RAE dictionary:

> envidia:
>   1. f. Tristeza o pesar del bien ajeno.
>   2. f. Emulación, deseo de algo que no se posee.
>
> celos: [I'm only citing the plural form)
>   3. Envidia del bien ajeno, o recelo de que el propio o pretendido llegue a ser alcanzado por otra persona.

So in Spanish they can be seen as partial synonyms, although `celos` has the additional meaning of `fear of somebody gaining your own goods`.

Reading the definitions of `envy` and `jealous` (`jealousy` redirects there), I think that your translations are pretty accurate.

PS. It is worth noting that in Spanish there is the expression `envidia sana`. The purported meaning is the "just like envy but without the resentment, just wishing that I could have/do the same".

Comment: Gracias por señalándome en la dirección al [**Diccionario de la Real Academia Española (DRAE)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diccionario_de_la_lengua_espa%C3%B1ola).  Hace un año, mis habilidades con español no fueron tan buenas.  De hecho, sólo comencé a utilizar el DRAE regularmente hace aproximadamente un año.  ¡Quizás fue tu respuesta que me influyó!